# Button click() gives strange problem in selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send a custom message to my connections in Linkedin using Selenium Python. Partial code is as follows:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pyperclip
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class ConnectionsPage:
    def __init__(self, browser, wait):
        self.browser = browser
        self.wait = wait

    def test_message(self):
        all_elements = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.list-style-none')
        excluded_list = [# Excluded list]
        print(len(excluded_list))
        try:
            for ele in all_elements:
                name = ele.find_element_by_css_selector('.mn-connection-card__name.t-16.t-black.t-bold').text
                if name in excluded_list:
                    print(f"{name} - Excluded")
                else:
                    print(f"{name} - Included")
                    msg_btn = ele.find_element_by_css_selector(
                        '.message-anywhere-button.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--secondary')
                    msg_btn.click()
                    sleep(2)
                    self.wait.until(
                        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".msg-form__contenteditable"))).click()
                    sleep(1)
                    msg = "My custom message"
                    pyperclip.copy(msg)
                    self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".msg-form__contenteditable").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")
                    send_btn = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.msg-form__send-button.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--1')
                    send_btn.click()
                    # self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", send_btn)
                    # actions = ActionChains(self.browser)
                    # actions.click(send_btn)
                    # actions.perform()
                    sleep(2)
                    self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".js-msg-close").click()
                    self.wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js-msg-close")))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

home_page = HomePage(browser, wait)
sleep(2)
login_page = home_page.go_to_login_page()
sleep(2)
feed_page = login_page.login("my_email", "my_password")
sleep(2)
conn_page = feed_page.go_to_my_connections_page()
sleep(2)
conn_page.test_message()
```

The problems is in this lines :

```
send_btn = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.msg-form__send-button.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--1')
send_btn.click()
```

The code works perfectly and the send button is clicked, but Linkedin says : There was an issue sending your message. Please try again...

But, when I try to click the send button manually, there's no problem, it just sends the message.

I think I'm messing up with a small thing which I couldn't figure out.

Comment: trying to replicate your issue locally but script is throwing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: ```excluded_list = [# Excluded list]```

Maybe this line is making the issue..Give it another try...@DipakBachhav

Comment: excluded_list = [# Excluded list] .. This one, I edited for posting here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed...

I don't know what the issue was...when I tried the code after some days...it worked like a charm...